# Template file path

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to open and read this html file with in my django project, however i'm getting this 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.html'.

```
html = 'test.html'
open_html = open(html, 'r')
soup =  BeautifulSoup(open_html, "html5lib")
open_html.close()
```

But the template path seems to work fine when rendered

```
template = 'test.html'
context = {
}
return render(request, template, context)

TEMPLATES = [
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
]
```

I know my templates are suppose to go into my apps folders, however i like to keep them in one folder when developing and debugging.

Comment: `html = 'test.html'
open_html = open(html, 'r')` this code does not take whole path. html has only file name test.html but BeautifulSoup require full path.    instead of `html = 'test.html'` this provide actual path of file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are trying to access file from templates so you need to add full path

Try following solution

```
from your_project_name.settings import BASE_DIR
path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'test.html')
with open(path, 'r') as open_html:
    soup =  BeautifulSoup(open_html, "html5lib")
```

Hope this is help you